# How do I make a command block work at any time a redstone signal is active?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

I have a teleporter system I'm setting up where a teleporter will only trigger if you open a trapped chest and stand on a specific block. I'd like for it to work so that the block is somewhere away from the chest a little ways and you have to go to the appropriate location before the time limit, and the command block will teleport you at any point during that open window.

My setup is as follows:
Trapped Chest → Pulse Extender → Command Block

This is my command block code:

```
execute positioned 265 78 53 as @a[distance=..2] at @s run teleport @a 262 80 59
```

Currently it only triggers if you're already standing on the designated block when you open the chest. Is there any way to make it work so it will trigger at any point during the length of time opened by the pulse extender when you step on the block? I'm fine with both redstone and command code solutions.

My fallback plan is to swap out the pulse extender for a pulse delayer, so you have time to get into position before it triggers, but I'd prefer to have a window of opportunity if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Simple answer

With your pulse extender and connected command block, set that command block to Repeat mode. It will turn purple and it will then repeatedly execute the command while it still receives a redstone input.

Your command is also overly complex. This will do:

```
tp @a[x=265,y=78,z=53,dx=0,dy=0,dz=0] 262 80 59
```

This works by creating a 1×1×1 cube at coordinates (265, 78, 53) and teleporting all players in that zone to the target location.

Comment: This works, thank you!